# Формирование библиотеки для Android с другими aar и jar библиотеками внутри

Tags: java, android, aar

Я работаю над библиотекой для Android приложений (aar), которая зависит от другой aar библиотеки (в виде файла, не размещена ни в одном репозитории), трех jar библиотек (тоже в виде файлов) и еще нескольких зависимостей с публичных репозиториев.

Пока шла разработка библиотека без проблем работала в sample-приложении. Но при необходимости ее опубликовать, я получаю aar файл, в котором нет внешних зависимостей и нет внутренней aar библиотеки. При этом jar файлы находятся внутри полученного aar. Но с jar файлами есть другая проблемма, один из них внутри себя имеет файлы ресурсов, к которым он обращается через ClassLoader.getResources(). Так вот, при формировании итоговой aar библиотеки jar файлы добавляются без этих ресурсов.

Как правильно сделать так, чтобы моя библиотека могла быть подключена к проекту android приложения как один файл, без необходимости вместе с ней подключать все ее зависимости также в виде файлов? Библиотека закрытая, опубликовать ее в каком-то открытом репозитории не могу.

Пример структуры проекта:

```
- myLib
-- libs
--- lib1.aar
--- lib2.jar
--- lib3.jar
--- lib4.jar
-- src
-- build.gradle
```

Внутри build.gradle зависимости подключены вот так:

```
dependencies {
    api fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'
    api (name: 'lib1', ext: 'aar')
    api 'com.some.another.lib5:1.2.3.'
    api 'com.some.another.lib6:3.4.5.'
}
```